# How to simplify an expression with a sequence of products within a sequence of sums.

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I am trying to figure out how to solve inhomogenous 1. Order Difference Equations
and i have been given the following exercise.

$$
y(n+1)=(n+1)y(n)+2^n(n+1)!, \quad y(0)=c, \quad n>0
$$

I use the following formula to find $y(n)$.
$$
y(k+1) = \Bigg[\prod_{i=n_0}^{k}a(i)\Bigg]y_0+\sum_{r=n_0}^{k}\Bigg[\prod_{i=r+1}^{k}a(i)\Bigg]g(r)
$$
Thus giving me:
$$
(1)\qquad y(n) = \Bigg[\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(i+1)\Bigg]\cdot c + \sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\Bigg[\prod_{i=r+1}^{n-1}(i+1)\Bigg]2^r(r+1)!
$$

I know the solution is,

$$
y(n)=n!(2^n+c-1)
$$

I'm having problems simplifying (1), you can follow my train of thought in the following deriviation:

$$
(1) \qquad y(n) = \Bigg[\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(i+1)\Bigg]\cdot c + \sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\Bigg[\prod_{i=r+1}^{n-1}(i+1)\Bigg]2^r(r+1)!
$$

$$
(1.a) \qquad y(n) = cn! + \sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\Bigg[\prod_{i=r+1}^{n-1}(i+1)\Bigg]2^r(r+1)!
$$

And now i get:
$$
(1.b) \qquad y(n) = cn! + \sum_{r=0}^{n-1}n!2^r(r+1)!
$$

Where i should get:
$$
(1.b*) \qquad y(n) = cn! + \sum_{r=0}^{n-1}n!2^r
$$

I simply can't wrap my head around how:
$$
\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\Bigg[\prod_{i=r+1}^{n-1}(i+1)\Bigg]2^r(r+1)!=\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}n!2^r
$$

Comment: Well you've got an extra factor of $(r+1)!$.  We have $$\prod_{i=r+1}^{n-1}{(i+1)}=\frac{n!}{(r+1)!}$$

Comment: Thanks, that is fulfilling.